# Symfony3 onSecurityInteractiveLogin logout and set flash

Tags: symfony, listener, fosuserbundle

I port project on symfony2.2 to symfony3.4. I have LoginListener with onSecurityInteractiveLogin event. When user logged, i need to do something check. If check failed user must be logout and show some flash messages. Code below works fine in symfony2. In Symfony3 all works good except flash messages, it doesn't show, i think that session cleaned. How to show flash messages in login form?

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {

        // Make some check based on user info in database...

        $check = true || false;

        // Logout user and set flash
        if(!$check){
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $session = $this->container->get('session');
            $session->start();
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('error','message');
            $request->request->set('_target_path', '/logout');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution to use custom 
[Authenticator class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html). In constructor inject Session. You can make your check in `checkCredentials()` method, push an error into FlashBag here and return false, if user don`t pass your check.

Or you can use your custom [user checker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html)